# error while adding products to the cart in broadleaf -SITE

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Have Tried to add the products from merchandise-Men and merchandise-Women it will gives the following error while adding Products to the Cart.

Here is the screen shot of the Error:

http://i.prntscr.com/Dr_5CBezQKWIEOKGanBbZw.png

Here is the Server Log of Error:

http://i.prntscr.com/6FML0e3QQleo4vV_fL_6xQ.png

Please Help to Solve the problem.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Check if you have cookies disabled.

Comment: no cookies are working properly other products are added successfully but only merchandise men and women category only giving the error